# Select Text in a multiline textbox, move it to another multiline textbox on a button click in C#

Tags: c#

I have a problem that I haven't come across yet that I hope some of you may help me with. I am trying to select a single line, either the fist, second, or last line in a multiline textbox and move it to another multiline textbox with a button click in C#. I am unsure how to select just a single line at a time, then add it to the other multiline textbox. If anyone has some insight, that would be great! Thank you!

Brent

Comment: Did you consider using ListBox instead?

Comment: While I like the answer I gave, I should also point out that AlexM's question here has merit. If you are using a TextBox to allow the users to enter freeform text, this is an appropriate use. If the text in the box is going to be controlled by the program and the user just gets to move it from one box to another, then ListBox is the best way to do this. (And probably the easiest)

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming that you are defining a "line" as a complete string of characters separated by other similar strings with a newline character, and not simply as the string of characters visible in a single horizontal plane in a text field with word wrap property set to true.....

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, ClickEventArgs e)
{
     //get the values of both boxes
     string value1 = TextBox1.Text.Trim();
     string value2 = TextBox2.Text.Trim();

     //split the value from the source box on its new line characters
     string[] parts = value1.split(Environment.NewLine);
     string last_line = parts[parts.length -1];

     //add the last row from the source box to the destination box
     value2 += (Environment.NewLine + last_line);

     //set the last_line in the source to an empty string
     parts[parts.Length -1] = String.Empty;

     //put the new values back in their text boxes
     TextBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, parts).Trim();
     TextBox2.Text = value2;
}
```

If you are dealing with visible line and word wrapped that is a whole 'nother ball game and the answer is dependant on if you are talking ASP, or Win App. Also, this was written off the cuff, so you may need to tweak a character or two to get it to compile. No Warranties, LOL.

Comment: Awesome guys. All these solutions worked. But To answer the question about the listbox, I changed it to a listbox so I kind of wasted your time for being an idiot. But I am sure I will use one of these solutions in the future! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work:

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, ClickEventArgs e)
{    
   string text = TextBox1.Text;

    // spliting text on the basis on newline.
    string[] myArray = text.Split(new char[] { '\n' });

    foreach (string s in myArray)
    {
       //Line by line copy
       TextBox2.Text += s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Lines.Length > 0)
    {
        textBox2.Text += textBox1.Lines[textBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(textBox1.SelectionStart)];
    }
}
```

What it is doing is using the [GetLineFromCharIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.getlinefromcharindex.aspx) with the SelectionStart caret location as the char Index to pull the Line out of the [TextBox.Lines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines.aspx) array